# Comparing two columns of the dataframe against a new dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have two dataframes which looks like

```
   team  points
0     1     2.5
1     2     3.2
2     5     5.8
3     3     2.8
4     4     1.9
```

and:

```
   team1  team2
0      1      5
1      2      4
2      3      1
```

Expected output should give me a new column with the winner (more points) :

```
team1   team2   winner
 1         5       5
 2         4       2
 3         1       3
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. People can help you debug your code here, not simply code for you. Can you please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [mcve], which has the efforts you made and the error(s) you get in your code? From the question, it is highly unclear what rules are at use here.

Comment: Thank you @harvpan for the information. I am new to SO .I will make sure i will put clear picture next time.

Answer (score 3):

here is a way using [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html),[`df.idxmax()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) and [`df.lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html):

```
s=df2.applymap(df1.set_index('team')['points'].get).idxmax(1)
```

Or better alternative courtesy @user3483203

```
s=df2.stack().map(df1.set_index('team')['points']).unstack().idxmax(1)
#s.tolist() gives ['team2', 'team1', 'team1']
df2['winner']=df2.lookup(s.index,s)
print(df2)
```

---

```
   team1  team2  winner
0      1      5       5
1      2      4       2
2      3      1       3
```

Comment: An alternative to `applymap` is `df2.stack().map(df1.set_index('team')['points']).unstack().idxmax(1)`, which should be much faster on large inputs.  Still doubtful it will beat an approach that drops to `numpy`

Comment: @user3483203 agreed ,would update your suggestion though :) Appreciate it, thank you

Answer (score 3):

Trying to avoid `applymap` and use `lookup`+`reshape`

```
x = df.set_index('team').lookup(df2.values.ravel('F'), ["points"]*df2.size)
                        .reshape(df2.shape, order='F')
                        .argmax(1)

df2['winner'] = df2.lookup(df2.index, df2.columns[x])
```

---

```
   team1  team2  winner
0      1      5       5
1      2      4       2
2      3      1       3
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution only using [**pandas.Series.map**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) , [**DataFrame.stack**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [**DataFrame.unstack**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
df_match['winner']=( df_match.stack()
                             .map(df.set_index('team')['points'])
                             .unstack()
                             .max(axis=1)
                             .map(df.set_index('points')['team']) )
```

---

```
print(df_match)

   team1  team2  winner
0      1      5       5
1      2      4       2
2      3      1       3
```

Answer (score 0):

My "simple" solution:

```
df3= df2.replace(df1.set_index("team").points.to_dict()) 
df2["winner"]= np.where(df3.team1>=df3.team2,df2.team1,df2.team2)
```